# Sci fi book about aliens, girl awakes to everyone motionless

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

I read a young adult book where girl wakes to discover everyone motionless whether they are driving, walking, sitting etc. She's in a town or city. She discovers creatures/aliens come and kill and eat people. She hides in a shop and watches this happen. She has to hide from the creatures.

Comment: Hi Helen, could you provide any details about when (year) you read this, whether it was an old or recent book at the time, any other details such as what the cover looked like? The more information you can provide the better.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: It was definitely within the last ten years, i cant remember the cover. I think.the people came awake just bfore creatures arrived, i recall the girl seeing this + seeing the look of terror on their faces. It was first in a series.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a little like Scott Westerfield's [Midnighters trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnighters_trilogy), the first of which is The Secret Hour. Jessica Day moves to a new town where she discovers that when she wakes up at midnight everything in town is frozen for an hour each night. Creatures called Darklings live in this frozen hour, occasionally eating the odd human who strays into the hour. The Darklings attack Jessica, who manages to fight them off with the help of the only other people who can move around in the secret hour.

Comment: Thanx for comment, its not midnighters, ive read those books. what has happened affects whole world, most people are made motionless permanently until killed/eaten. Think there are some others like the girl not affected. Not sure but think it was written later than midnighters.